# In Typescript, Calls methods in Object with string typed key

Tags: typescript

I want to call methods in Object with string typed key, but it doesn't work.

Can I get some ways to solve this?

```
type Methods = {
    foo?: (v: string) => string;
    bar?: (v: number) => number;
    baz?: (v: boolean) => boolean;
    hello?: (v: number) => string;
};
  
function execute<
    I extends Methods,
    K extends keyof I,
    V extends Parameters<I[K]>[0],
    R extends ReturnType<I[K]>
>(methods: I, key: K, value: V): R {
    return methods[key](value);
}

const methods: Methods = {
    foo(v) { return `${v}blah`; },
    bar(v) { return v + 1; },
    baz(v) { return !v; },
    hello(v) { return String(v); },
};

const foo = execute(methods, 'foo', 'hello'); // returns string
const bar = execute(methods, 'bar', 123); // returns number
const baz = execute(methods, 'baz', true); // returns boolean
const mem = execute(methods, 'hello', 123); // returns string
```

[Link to Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAzlAvFA3gWACgpioAzJJAfgC4oAKAN1rWACcBLAOwHMBKLAHxQWHHgG5CJKACMAhqxr0mUTgFcAttIit%20mIWs3aJREnIBeixrWkUANhFmddQm0nuPjUhBFu2qtKxUNLR1BYTYubmMAX08oQlJVTgBjYHYkTigIAA8IZNVgCAAeSRIASSzsws50WHhkdAAaUuIAaUrq2oBrCBAkUigy5pNiADUOiBqMAAV5WXV4bTQisoBtVoBdAVWABg3hqQAlCamoQ-hVVk4AFXBitc2BQgE6BcRUNFohqB6QWlbGlAGLJbKoILRRrxaMd8CMoKwLlcoG8GmhVr8NowQWDeDFCIRkhkWMj6h9aHB3rVsLCpOQkIx%20Dh4YjMgADAAkOAY0WktlkCFZYig0QOpnkDNwzOAl0yDCgAGooABGIUiloyWRmCVMhHSpEAQgYqtFxG8vnpDEZUplUAAyhEeAzjYRYviCITOMS6VhKnkChBXqSmlAAOR0kOAkNmvwh3FQAD08etVwwIkiBKJwA1rB9OT9hUDlLQkbkrAjyoATABmOOJ5OeoKGVgZz1Z8y53L5Asoj4lzXltg4oV13UyjCudycFvEhbqDv5gM94NRnwxwFK6u1pOjlPhUTcQhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAzlAvFAShAxkgE4oA8awRAlgHYDmANFABQB07AhkXWgFxQcaIANoBdAJRYAfAKFSA3AFgAUFCgqAZgFca+YFSQ0oEAB4EtwCKRVq1ASWMnLNdLHjJ0DG7YDSj564A1hAgSBpQdl7KUswAtu6ofBFMwSD8PkzsrABuHAA2WhBJAApcHPGWRGikdsI+olLi-HjAWkQ0ACrgVrX1MgDe3mpE8G1GFR5owqmibOy5BUXiSsoAvioqhDQUUBOJWFCDqrYaSEjM2fwU1PSS-VAjre1QAAYAJP3ZqwBGeRwIL3kUFWUVsUG+XAu-BoWli3wgRDuD1Gz2yUAA1FAAIxAkFDcEcABeUPBZzyEEESMeYygAEJsrjQbYEBA8nlzpcoDpAjQkAB3GhUlFGADKlFodAuy2BUVWK02hh2pyQB1M5kscQSnigAHJlTqmDrrhKddKAPRm5FPbZQY30BXbYAEoiqsz4CwQTWIRKGiFEA3YgBMAGZzZbqe0MDC4QiHTsIYTXerPXttTqEwHKIUw1axhhvmSKTQ4074rEk+6Nam0IaWWykAGsSGcxGbXa6BtlCoUAQ-iMoFsdhx+IIQCtB07vgcOBjsfIgA)

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to clarify the structure of the `Methods` type.

Comment: @grace please elaborate

Comment: Oh, I was confused. The way you gave me was the way I wanted it! Thank you!